# how to get total length of video in video view in android

Tags: android

I have a problem that I want to get total length of video which is running in Video View for this I am using getDuration Method of video view but it always returns -1 when I am comparing it with currentPosition. Actually I want that if video's currentposition is equals to the total length of the video then it should start from the 0th position means starting. Mean I want to say that I want to compare Video current position with the total length of the video, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

**Code:**

```
videoPosition=VideoPositionFinding(IDValue,video.getDuration());
    video.seekTo(videoPosition);
    if(video.getCurrentPosition()==video.getDuration()){
        videoPosition=0;
    }
     locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
     System.out.println("The Video Duration: "+video.getCurrentPosition());

     video.start();
```

Comment: Post your code here so that we know what is the problem

Comment: See again I have edited the question with code

Answer (score 18):

To get total length of video use code:

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()  {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {                         
                long duration = videoView.getDuration();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Beware this sometimes returns ms and sometimes Seconds

Comment: @htafoya are you serious? That would be a joke, it is not possible

Comment: @kolboc yes I am. I'm not sure why. Probably if the length was less than a second then it returns ms. But be sure to check it out.

Comment: propably I won't because I ended up using MediaMetadataRetriever.
but thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 9):

To get length of video use the below code

```
myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int duration=mp.getDuration()/1000;
            int hours = duration / 3600; 
            int minutes = (duration / 60) - (hours * 60);
            int seconds = duration - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60) ;
            String formatted = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "duration is " + formatted ,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use below code :

```
int duration = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.fromFile(new File(video_path))).getDuration();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think there is not a direct way to implement this, but by these function you can done this.
you should try .

public int getBufferPercentage ()

public int getDuration ()

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using LOCATION_SERVICE to get the video position? The LOCATION_SERVICE is meant for pinpointing device's location. Refer to this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).

Comment: location Service is not for getting video position, it is not for your concern

Comment: In that case, then don't place that line of code in there. It's very misleading