# VideoView time duration

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-seekbar

I am using videoview to play videos from urls. when i play video the current time is some sec more than the total time duration of the video.

`04-05 17:20:27.457 9342-9342/exoplayer.com.videoview V/TOTAL: 00:45
04-05 17:20:27.557 9342-9342/exoplayer.com.videoview V/CURRENT: 00:46`

```
 public String stringForTime(long timeMs) {
    mFormatBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    mFormatter = new Formatter(mFormatBuilder, Locale.getDefault());
    long totalSeconds = timeMs / 1000;
    int seconds = (int) (totalSeconds % 60);
    int minutes = (int) ((totalSeconds / 60) % 60);
    int hours = (int) (totalSeconds / 3600);
    mFormatBuilder.setLength(0);
    if (hours > 0) {
        return mFormatter.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds).toString();
    } else {
        return mFormatter.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds).toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a answer. I'm just giving you idea how you can do this.

Use something like this:

```
public String milliSecondsToTimer(long milliseconds) {
    String finalTimerString = "";
    String secondsString = "";

    // Convert total duration into time
    int hours = (int) (milliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    int minutes = (int) (milliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60);
    int seconds = (int) ((milliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) % (1000 * 60) / 1000);
    // Add hours if there
    if (hours > 0) {
        finalTimerString = hours + ":";
    }

    // Prepending 0 to seconds if it is one digit
    if (seconds < 10) {
        secondsString = "0" + seconds;
    } else {
        secondsString = "" + seconds;
    }

    finalTimerString = finalTimerString + minutes + ":" + secondsString;

    // return timer string
    return finalTimerString;
}
```

Follow these links:

[How to Display time of videoview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130324/how-to-display-time-of-videoview-in-android)

[how to get total length of video in video view in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964256/how-to-get-total-length-of-video-in-video-view-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

I did it using joda time, there's probably a better way but i think this is neater than the solution listed above

```
private String setTime(long elapsed) {
    final String PADDED_TIME_FORMAT = "00%s";
    final Period duration = new Period(elapsed);
    final String hours = String.format(PADDED_TIME_FORMAT, duration.getHours());
    final String minutes = String.format(PADDED_TIME_FORMAT, duration.getMinutes());
    final String seconds = String.format(PADDED_TIME_FORMAT, duration.getSeconds());
    return String.format("%s:%s:%s",
            hours.substring(hours.length() -2, hours.length()),
            minutes.substring(minutes.length() -2, minutes.length()),
            seconds.substring(seconds.length() -2, seconds.length()));
}
```

Comment: The easiest and better solution.